# Basic Model View Controller not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am fairly new to programming and I'm creating my first application using the model view controller structure.

However; every time I try to output `public/home/index/andres`, it only displays `Array ( [0] => 1 )`.

My expected output would've been:

```
Array (
    [0] => home
    [1] => index
    [2] => andres
)
```

Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Below is my `.htaccess` file as well as my `app.php` files.

**.htaccess:**

```bash
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=1 [QSA,L]
```

**app.php:**

```php
<?php

class App 
{
    protected $controller = 'home';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        print_r($this->parseUrl());
    }

    public function parseUrl()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['url']))
        {
           return $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)); 

        }
    }

}?>
```